# Can you check for HTML entities in text, and can you save the Math.PI function in variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a calculator and I'm trying to add a button which allows you to use pi in your equations. You press it and it puts the text `&pi;` into the display. When I then check if the display contains the text `&pi;`,nothing happens. If I make it check for the character π, it then replaces it with the desired Math.PI. Then the variable num1 is set to Math.PI, but when I try to do an equation with it, e.g. pi x 3, it just says NaN.

Can I set a variable to Math.PI and have it actually used as a number?

Code:

```
  text = document.getElementById("display").value;
  if(text.includes("π") == true) {
    num1 = text.replace("π", Math.PI);
  }
```

When I look at what num1 is though, it is just NaN.

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDBLD80VEUOO @EmilioGrisolía

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted (or as an executable stack snippet, in cases where that makes sense) - _not_ just dumped onto some external platform. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line in your `operation` function

```js
text.replace("π", "Math.PI")
```

with this:

```js
text.replace("π", Math.PI)
```

This is because the first sets the string to the actual string `"Math.PI"`, which will evaluate to `NaN` when parsed into a number, but the second sets the string to the actual value of `Math.PI`, or `"3.14159..."`, which will actually evaluate to a number when parsed.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for this. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you!